# Suggest models for prediction based on small sample data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, model-selection, small-sample

I am not a traditional statistics guy. I am from an electrical engineering background. So, spare me for lack of jargon.

The model is to be used for predicting agricultural output based on previous data. One method is Grey model prediction, which need around 4 to 8 sample data for prediction. Could you think of any other model?

E.g.: I have national agriculture output of sugarcane from 1996 to 2010 on an annual basis. That accounts for 15 data. Now using these data, I wish to design a prediction model and use it to forecast the next 2 or 3 years of national production output of sugarcane.
My confusion is about which model will give me the best forecasting result for such a small amount of data.
Please let me know anything else is lacking in the description.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you say more about your data & your situation? I'm not sure if there's enough here to make this question answerable.

Comment: It's not even clear what you mean by 'low sample data' (small values, or few data points?), let alone the rest of it. Please clarify extensively. I have no clear idea what you are asking.

Comment: @gung. I have put in some details. Let me know if needed more.

Comment: I added the time-series tag and voted for re-opening. This question can be answered now. @ron: I don't know the "Grey model", do you have a reference?

Comment: "Forecasting agricultural output with an improved grey forecasting model based on the genetic algorithm" -by Shang-Ling Ou. @Stephan Kolassa: for your reference.

Comment: @ron: thanks. Well, nothing against *Computers and Electronics in Agriculture* (and I don't have access to the article), but I think the specialized journals for forecasting will be more helpful, i.e., the *International Journal of Forecasting* (in which the M3 competition was published) and the *Journal of Forecasting*.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for *time series forecasting*. I recommend [this free textbook](https://otexts.com/fpp3/).

Histories of 15 yearly data points are not uncommon in time series forecasting. For instance, the very first one of the series used in the classical [M3 competition](https://web.archive.org/web/20151203110057/http://www.forecastingprinciples.com/files/Makridakia-The%20M3%20Competition.pdf) has only 14 data points. Let's use R and look at this dataset.

```
library(Mcomp)
M3[[1]]
M3[[1]]$x
```

We can fit an Exponential Smoothing model using `ets()` (for "Error, Trend, Seasonality"), which attempts to automatically choose the correct model in terms of trend, seasonality and error - seasonality is irrelevant for yearly data. Let's forecast using this model. `forecast()` will give us a point forecast as well as (by default) 80% and 95% prediction intervals. We can also plot the original series, the point forecasts and the prediction intervals.

```
ets.model <- ets(M3[[1]]$x)
forecast(ets.model,h=3)
plot(forecast(ets.model,h=3))
```

[image: ETS forecast]

Similarly, `auto.arima()` will try to fit the best ARIMA model:

```
arima.model <- auto.arima(M3[[1]]$x)
forecast(arima.model,h=3)
plot(forecast(arima.model,h=3))
```

[image: ARIMA forecast]

The textbook I linked to above will bring you up to speed on both Exponential Smoothing and ARIMA, as well as other aspects of forecasting, like model selection and accuracy measurement. As I noted in my comment above, I don't know a "Grey model", and after a couple of years in this field, I would rather suggest using standard methods like Exponential Smoothing and ARIMA than an unknown method - after all, there are reasons why these methods have evolved to be the mainstay in time series forecasting.

Happy forecasting!

Comment: What about the bayseian model. How effective is that? And can that one be used here?

Comment: Bayesian models are certainly possible in forecasting. Essentially, you posit some model and describe the parameters by prior distributions, which will then be updated by the observations. However, I think it would be helpful to first understand "vanilla" forecasting on the one hand and "standard" Bayesian statistics (without time series-related complications) on the other hand before delving into the combination of the two.